# How can combine different pages in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let say I separate my page into 4 parts. One is banner, one is login, one is main, another is footer. Banner and Footer is static, it won't change. and login is based on different user right or login status, lastly the main is based on many thing to do it. So, I have 4 parts of element:

```
http://localhost:8888/my_app/index.php/static_page/banner

http://localhost:8888/my_app/index.php/static_page/footer

http://localhost:8888/my_app/index.php/user/login_fragment

http://localhost:8888/my_app/index.php/system/main_fragment
```

But the user only see one page, but it combine all the staff in...So, instead of using iframe to put them together, how can I let these page separate the logic, but can combine in one view? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to share what I have done. Although not an original idea(do not remember from where I got), hopefully this will help you. I have an 'includes' [application/views/includes] folder, which contains the following files:

> footer.php, header.php, navigation.php and template.php

Now the code in the template.php is as the following:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header'); 
$this->load->view($main_content); 
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

For usage, let me give you an example:

```
$data = array (
  'page_title'    => 'Users Listing',
  'title'         => 'Users Listing',
  'main_content'  => 'users/showlist',            
);

$this->load->view('includes/template', $data));
```

The elements in the $data array, will be available in the view [application/views/users/showlist.php] as $page_title, $title etc. You can also send arrays or HTML content.

Comment: Using pretty much the same approach myself, and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Just call load->view multiple times

in your controller method:

```
function index()
{
 $this->load->view("banner",array(/** some parameters if you want **/));
 $this->load->view("main",array(/** some parameters if you want **/));
 $this->load->view("footer"); // this one doesn't need parameters maybe
}
```

See the [views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) documentation page

Note: within a view file itself (e.g. inside banner.php) you can call load-view again to insert a nested view.

Note2: you can also return the result of load->view into a variable if you don't want to output it right away, by adding a true parameter as the 3rd parameter:

```
$login_box = $this->load->view("login",array(),true);

// $login_box contains the view html.

echo $login_box; // or pass it as a parameter to another view if you want
```

Comment: but I have some main logic....in the controller to do getting information from db, and some checking, it I can it directly, it won't load all the data...if I call the view directly.

Comment: @ted. not 100% sure what you mean but you should load info from the database and do the processing in your controller method, then you can pass some data to your views using the second parameter (check the link to the Views documentation)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
$this->load->view('filename');
```

Can be used as many times as you want in the same controller function, and they will appear in the right order.

What you did is separate in controllers parts that must be used in the same controller. I suppose you have these in files like

```
/application/controllers/static_page.php
/application/controllers/user.php
/application/controllers/system.php
```

And, without massive modification of CodeIgniter, you can't call a controller from another controller, which is what was stopping you. If you have to use the same processing code for many functions, you have to make either a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html), that you can use anywhere, or the more elegant solution, that is having common controller functions in /libraries/MY_Controller.php.

MY_Controller.php would be called always before a controller is called

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // you can do any kind of processing here
        // in example if you have some view counter
        // this place is always called
    }

    function a_generic_function($rawdata)
    {
        // do some processing here

        return $data;
    }


}
```

Then, you will be able to use this function in any of your controllers:

```
$this->a_generic_function($rawdata);
```

Now, the smartest way to deal with a header+footer is making a "layout" file that contains both the header and the footer.

Here's an example of layout.php view:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>This page has been made by <?php echo $user_name; ?>/header>

        <div id="main" role="main">
            <?php echo $main_content_view; ?>
        </div>

        <footer>Write your footer here</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You see there's $main_content_view in the middle.

With this you will do, in your controller:

```
// add the HTML for the login to the variable
// TRUE means we don't output it in the browser, but put it in a String
$this->viewdata["main_content_view"] = $this->load->view('login', $data, TRUE);

// want to add more data? just ADD it to the variable, like a String
$this->viewdata["main_content_view"] += $this->load->view('main', $data, TRUE);

// done? send it to the layout, and pass it the $this->viewdata
$this->load->view('layout', $this->viewdata);
```

What else can you do with this? You can use the $this->viewdata like:

```
$this->viewdata["title"] = 'Function title';
$this->viewdata["user_name"] = $user_name;
```

so you can edit your layout as much as you want like any other view.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Sturgeon has written a popular template library for Codeigniter which will do what you want in a smarter way than what has been described in the other answers so far. You can read its documentation here: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/

The documentation might take a while to understand because it lacks examples.

You can download the template library here: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template